# If the moon produced energy like the Sun would it radiate the same energy and light on Earth as the Sun?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, visible-light, cosmology

I would like to know if the moon where to shine like the sun would the Earth get the same energy and light as it is getting now from the Sun?

Comment: "shine like the sun" is too vague, all it says is that some light and energy comes here, it doesn't say how much. If it's too little, the ocean and even the atmosphere would freeze. If it's just enough, then life could survive. If it's too much, the Earth's atmosphere would evaporate and the surface would melt.

Comment: This whole question is too vague.  "Life as we know it"?  Viruses? Bacteria? Plants?  Higher life forms?  The ecosystem as a whole?  Present ecosystems or ecosystems of the past?

Comment: Rolled back from an edit that entirely changed the question....

Answer (score 2):

Very roughly:  If "shine like the sun" means "have the same surface temperature as the sun", then, up to a constant, the apparent brightness of either is $R^2/D^2$, where $R$ is radius (so $R^2$ --- again up to a constant --- is surface area) and $D$ is distance.  But $R^2/D^2$ is about the same for the sun and the moon, as evidenced by the fact that they appear about the same size in the sky.   So the two apparent brightnesses will be roughly equal.

Comment: But only when the Moon is full, right? Sorry, couldn't resist...

Answer (score 0):

According to Stefan–Boltzmann law, the total radiation of a black body is proportional to $T^4$, where $T$ is the temperature. The Sun can be seen as an radiating black body. The power radiated per unit area is $P=\sigma T^4$. In addition, the wavelength at which the maximum radiation occurs happens at $\lambda=b\cdot T^{-1}$, where $b$ is known as Wien's displacement constant ($b=2.9\cdot 10^{−3} m\cdot K$).

Therefore, the color of light of an radiating Moon would depend of the temperature of the Moon. The energy received from the Moon would also depend on the area of the Moon and distance to the Moon:

$$P=\sigma T^4 4\pi R_{M}^2\frac{\pi R_{E}^2}{4\pi R_{E-M}^2},$$ where $R_M$ and $R_E$ are the radii of the Moon and the Earth respectively, and $R_{E-M}$ is the distance from the Earth to the Moon.

Answer (score -2):

Not a physicist, but I'll try...

The sun is a ball of hot hydrogen undergoing nuclear fusion. The moon cannot support fusion (if it could, it would be happening). It's a big rock, I think currently thought to be a chunk of the earth that got knocked off.

It's not like a candle that got blown out. Your question is kind of like saying "if rubber could conduct electricity, how much would it conduct"? Well it can't, if it could conduct it wouldn't be rubber.

Comment: I'd also add that a lot of midrashim don't make much sense. I'm not here to bash any body's beliefs, I grew up in a conservative house, attended an orthodox day school, and my wife is a fairly religious catholic woman. But I always got the sense that the midrashim were an intellectual exercise to explain things. If you're going to believe an old book that includes magic as fact, don't try to explain, just believe. But I'm an atheist so do what you want.

Comment: I am asking a hypothetical question which is: If the moon was a ball of hot hydrogen undergoing nuclear fision would it supply Earth with the necessary energy for life to exist? Yes, it is not that way and that is why it is a hypothetical question.

Comment: Understood. I think the answer is probably that it is far too small to even undergo fusion. You should rephrase the question to make it clear and hope an astronomer answers. Some may be scared away by the biblical language.

Comment: Interesting point; however, aren’t there scientist trying to start fussion here on Earth?  Surely if they can conceive of doing it in their  little laboratory then surely they can conceive of it working on the moon.

Comment: I think that all attempts at fusion here involve incredibly huge magnetic fields. Fusion relies on two hydrogens getting so close together that they stick and turn into helium. Both nuclei are positively charged and repel so you need some intense heat (h bomb), intense gravity (stars) or intense magnetic fields (labs) to get fusion going. Consider that jupiter doesn't have enough hydrogen to support start fusion.

Comment: The sun is a ball of hot gas roughly 50:50 hydrogen and helium warmed up by a relatively small nuclear reactor deep down at the very center. If hypothetically the nuclear reaction there suddenly stopped, the sun would remain a ball of hot gas and we would not notice any change for millions of years (except by using a neutrino detector).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the question but a comment indicating the impossibility of such an answer existing.